# PHP Smarty3 Как узнать какие плагины используются шаблоном?

Tags: php, smarty

Доброго времени суток.
Есть PHP шаблонизатор Smarty3, есть шаблон, в котором используются некоторые смартёвые же плагины.
Что то типа:

```
...
<div>{myPlugin}</div>
...
<div>{myAnotherPlugin}</div>
...
```

И вот мне интересно есть ли способ как-то выяснить (без самодельного парсера для шаблона) какие именно плагины были задействованы в конкретном шаблоне? Например получить на выходе что то типа:

```
array(
0=>'myPlugin',
1=>'myAnotherPlugin');
```

Ну или хоть как-то.

*Заранее спасибо!*

Comment: Что-то совсем вариантов нет? Да народ?